# Extending the basis

Tags: lattice-crypto, trapdoor

Suppose I have $A \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{n \times m},A_1 \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{n \times m},A_2 \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{n \times m}$. I am following the $\textbf{ExtBasis}$ algorithm of [this](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~cpeikert/pubs/bonsai.pdf) (Page No. 13). I construct $F = A~|| -AR_1 + A_1~|| -AR_2 + A_2$. $F \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{n \times 3m}$ and $R_1,R_2 \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{m \times m}$ are random matrices not known apriori. Can we find a basis for $F$ given bases for $A_1$ and $A_2$ ?

Finding a basis for $F$ knowing a basis for $A$ is an application of $\textbf{ExtBasis}$ algorithm where we set $A\cdot W = -(-AR_1 + A_1~|| -AR_2 + A_2)$(Please refer to the link above), or can we do it better ?